# Plotly Sankey diagram, how to display custom data on click, not on hover

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am creating a Sankey diagram using `plotly.graph_objects`, and no `dash`. I would like to keep it that way.
I export these diagrams as `html` files. So far so good.

I am wondering if the following is possible:

- I would like to display some specific data (e.g.: a numpy array) when clicking on a node.
- Importantly, to avoid cluttering the diagram, I would like these specific data not to be displayed on hover.
- So, using `customdata` and `hovertemplate` is not a valid solution for me I believe.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.